Mongo DB Aggregate => Lookup => combine lookup data property into root property array

Lot's a questions on Stack Overflow regarding Mongo DB, Aggregate, and lookup. However, I could not find direct answers to the issue I am struggling with.

Suppose we have two collections: Support and Images. The Support document has a property called instructions that is an array of objects, which each contain an image property that is the string value of the images collection id. During the aggregation, the support document is found during match (returning one support document), then I need the instructions array objects to each get their "image" property replaced with the found images from the lookup, and ultimately return the root support object with only the instrucitons.image property changed.
No new properties added, only use the instructions.image tag from each object in the instructions array to get the correct images, then replace those strings with the actual image value from the images array.

How is this done?
Is there any way to get access to the "localfield" in the lookup without using "let" if I was to use a lookup pipeline?
Could this all be done inside of a lookup pipeline?
What is the most efficient way of doing this?

    DB.support = [
    {
        _id: ObjectId("12345"),
        title: "Support",
        instructions: [
            {
                image: "image-id-string-one"
            },
            {
                image: "image-id-string-two"
            },
            {
                image: "image-id-string-three"
            },
        ]
    }]

    DB.images = [
    {
        _id: ObjectId("11111111"),
        id:"image-id-string-one",
        image: "actual-image-one"
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId("222222222"),
        id:"image-id-string-two",
        image: "actual-image-two"
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId("333333333"),
        id:"image-id-string-three",
        image: "actual-image-three"
    }]

    db.collection('support').aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "title": "Support"
        }
    },
    // Let's say we match on title and expect only one record from above match
    {
        "$unwind": "$instructions"
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "images",
            "localField": "instructions.image",
            "foreignField": "id",
            "as": "images"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$images"
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "instructions.image": "$images.image"
        }
    },
    // Remove images array artifact from lookup from object.
    {
        "$unset": ["images"]
    }])

    // So that the return object would look like this

    {
    _id: ObjectId("12345"),
    title: "Support",
    instructions: [
        {
            image: "actual-image-one"
        },
        {
            image: "actual-image-two"
        },
        {
            image: "actual-image-three"
        },
    ]}


// NOTE: I have tried so many ways to try to get to the above object but nothing.


something like this maybe https://mongoplayground.net/p/PGWnTISQ5QZ  or simply a project if not many fields to include/exclude https://mongoplayground.net/p/CxM7GhrgXqx or an unset https://mongoplayground.net/p/OL0Vz3GXXyT

@cmgchess Great examples. I will take a look at the many ways you provided. Might be worthwhile in answering this question with the actual queries to add value to this question. I can see that two of these work well. I will play with them to get the best result in speed now. Thanks!

sure i added as an answer :)

You were almost there.
The pipeline you show would result in a separate support document for each instruction, with the image field already replaced with the desired value.
From that point you would need to:

group the documents, saving a copy of the overall document, and pushing the instructions back into an array
replace each document with a the copy of the original, but with the instructions field overwritten with the newly assembled array.

This might look like:
{$group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"},
      instructions: {$push: "$instructions"}
}},
{$replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {"$mergeObjects": ["$doc",{instructions: "$instructions"}]}
}}

Playground
Result from adding those 2 stages:
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "instructions": [
      {"image": "actual-image-one"      },
      {"image": "actual-image-two"},
      {"image": "actual-image-three"}
    ],
    "title": "Support"
  }
]

Edit: Adding some additional explanation
In an aggregation pipeline there are some predefined system variables, accessed with the $$ prefix, listed at: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables
The $$ROOT variable refers to the current document as it was at the start of the current stage.
In the $group stage, the $first operator means take the value from only the first document in the group, so doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"} means to assign a new field named "doc" the entire first document into the group.  For this example, that means it is saving a copy of all of the fields so that we can include them in the final document later, i.e. doc is a temporary field.
The $replaceRoot stage takes an object with a single field named "newRoot".  Each existing document in the pipeline is discarded, and the value of the newRoot field is passed along the pipeline as the new document.
The $mergeObjects operator takes an array of documents and combines their fields to form a new documents.  If any fields occur in multiple documents in the array, the last value will be the one used.
In this case we create a new object with a single field instructions, to hold the array that was built in the $group stage, and merge that into the document in the doc field, which contains the original full document (which had only a single instruction).

It did not feel close. I had group in there with root at one point but it still didn't do what I wanted it to do. I also had mergeObjects in there but in the wrong place which kept throwing an error about pipeline. Could you explain a bit regarding "doc" and "newRoot" as I don't see them in the final object, which is the way I would like it but I don't get how they magically disappear.

Thanks for the playground as well. Good work!

A lookup and a project would be sufficient

Approach - assuming that there are many fields in a single image document and you just want to extract the required fields use $map so that you don't have to manually specify all the fields that are not needed.

db.support.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { title: "Support" }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "images",
      localField: "instructions.image",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "instructions"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      instructions: {
        $map: {
          input: "$instructions",
          as: "instruction",
          in: { image: "$$instruction.image" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

playground

Approach - if you don't mind manually defining all the fields that you want to exclude/include

db.support.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { title: "Support" }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "images",
      localField: "instructions.image",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "instructions"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      title: 1,
      "instructions.image": 1
    }
  }
])

playground
or using $unset
db.support.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { title: "Support" }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "images",
      localField: "instructions.image",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "instructions"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [ "instructions.id", "instructions._id" ]
  }
])

playground
